# GNU parallel log from remote hosts

Tags: gnu-parallel, clamav

I'm trying to run clamsccan using parallel.

path /mnt/data in mounted on each host from clamscan_servers

```
find /mnt/data -type f | parallel --sshloginfile clamscan_servers --jobs 32 --sshdelay 0.1 --results parallel_outdir clamscan --max-scansize=0 --max-filesize=0 --verbose {}
```

Parameter `--result parallel_outdir` creates a directory with per-file log. I assume it contains logs from all nodes from `clamscan_servers` file.

But I'd like to have two more things:

1. Know which server handled a particular file.
2. One-file summary, not separate log for each file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear exactly what you are looking for.

Maybe `--joblog my.log` will do the trick for you?

It contains which sshlogin is used and has a one line summary for each job.